# Pressure difference in water tanks at different heights

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose there are two tanks(airtight) fully filled with water.one is kept on top of a ten storey building and one on top of a twenty storeyed one.They are NOT interconnected.Will there be a pressure difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the airtight part. That just confuses the issue by making you deal with the air pressure (or lack of it) at the top and bottom.

The pressure depends on how far below the surface of the water you measure it.

The pressure on a unit of area is nothing but the weight of the water in a slender column from that unit of area all the way to the surface.

So if you measure at the surface, it is nothing.
If you measure at the bottom of each tank, it just depends on the height of the surface of the water above the bottom.

Comment: So you say that if i take a point h height above the bottom for each tank,the pressure will be equal irrespective at what height the tanks are kept?

Comment: @soumyadeep: Right, unless you want split hairs about gravity being less strong at the higher elevation :)